# Why doesn't Typescript allow to use the whole refined type?

Tags: typescript

I would expect that the following snipped compiles but it doesn't:

```
function f1(x: "A") {}
function f2(x: {member: "A"}) {}

let x: {member: "A" | "B"} = {member: "A"}
if (x.member == "A") {
    f1(x.member) // compiles
    f2(x) // doesn't compile
}
```

I wonder why that is?

Note that I'm compiling using the `strict` option.

My use case is that I want to write a typesafe updater function for immutable types that I find more ergonomic then what I have seen so far.

```
type Update1 = <Value, 
    K1 extends keyof Value>
    (value: Value, k1: K1, replacement: Value[K1]) => Value;

type Update2 = <Value, 
    K1 extends keyof Value, 
    K2 extends keyof Value[K1]>
    (value: Value, k1: K1, k2: K2, replacement: Value[K1][K2]) => Value;

type Update3 = <Value,
    K1 extends keyof Value,
    K2 extends keyof Value[K1],
    K3 extends keyof Value[K1][K2]>
    (value: Value, k1: K1, k2: K2, k3: K3, replacement: Value[K1][K2][K3]) => Value;

// ...

type Update = Update1 & Update2 & Update3; // ...

let update: Update = (...args: Array<any>) => {
    throw "to be implemented..."
};
```

This signature works very good in many cases:

```
interface Data {
    value1: number
    value2: {
        kind: "A", 
        aValue: number, 
        abValue: number
    } | {
        kind: "B", 
        bValue: number, 
        abValue: number
    }
}

let data: Data = undefined as any // dummy value

data = update(data, "value1", 42) // compiles as expected
data = update(data, "value1", "42") // doesn't compile as expected
data = update(data, "notExistent", 42 as any) // dosen't compile as expected
data = update(data, "value2", "abValue", 42) // compiles as expected
```

But it dosen't work when it comes to narrowed types:

```
if (data.value2.kind == "A") {
    data.value2.aValue // compiles, can access aValues
    data = update(data, "value2", "aValue", 42) // doesn't compile, not expected!
}
```

I think it doesn't work because typescript doesn't use the narrowed type for the type parameter `Value`. And when I supply it manually I can't assign `data` to it like in the first example where I can't call `f2` with `x`.

- Is this behavior intended? If yes, why?
- Is it a bug?
- Is there a workaround?

Comment: You may also be interested in [the last comment in this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052) which explains why `{member: "A"|"B"}` isn't equivelent to `{member: "A"} | {member: "B"}`

Comment: Yes, looks like I did something wrong while narrowing down my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are using here is [tagged unions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tagged-union-types). From the page that describes this feature:

> A discriminant property type guard is an expression of the form x.p == v, x.p === v, x.p != v, or x.p !== v, where p and v are a property and an expression of a string literal type or a union of string literal types. The discriminant property type guard narrows the type of x to those constituent types of x that have a discriminant property p with one of the possible values of v.

So in your first example the issue is that `x` is not of a union type, so there is no constituent to narrow `x` to. This would however work as expected:

```
let x: {member: "A" } | {member: "B"} = {member: "A"}
if (x.member == "A") {
    f1(x.member) // compiles
    f2(x) // works now !
}
```

Applying this logic to the more complex example, Data would have to be a union in order to have the possibility to narrow to one of the constituents of the union, so one might expect this to work:

```
interface DataA {
    value1: number
    value2: {
        kind: "A", 
        aValue: number, 
        abValue: number
    }
}
interface DataB {
    value1: number
    value2: {
        kind: "B", 
        bValue: number, 
        abValue: number
    }
}

let data: DataA | DataB = undefined as any // dummy value
if (data.value2.kind == "A") {
    data.value2.aValue // compiles, can access aValues
    data = update(data, "value2", "aValue", 42) // doesn't compile, not expected!
}
```

The above code does not however work, and this open [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758), regarding nested discriminated unions, proposes expanding the way type narrowing works to cover this as well.

The only work around would be to use a custom type guard:

```
function isDataA(data: DataA | DataB) : data is DataA {
    return data.value2.kind == "A";
}
if (isDataA(data)) {
    data.value2.aValue // compiles, can access aValues
    data = update(data, "value2", "aValue", 42) // compiles
}
```